# How to create a predefined local database in windows phone app

Tags: database

I am trying to create a local prayer alert app for windows phone. I want to include a predefined database and query from it.

**How do i create and query from it?**

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried using linq to sql but every time i have to add tuples to the database using a wizard.

**Is there anyway i can use something like xml?**

I have found something like this in your site, but i want all the data to be stored before the app is installed in phone

**[Local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292523/windows-phone-7-5-local-sql-database)**

Comment: Sure you can, if it's reasonably small you can just use IsolatedStorage and pull the entire thing into memory, then query it using LINQ to XML

Comment: can u show me a demo code as I am a beginner..